# Applying Zorn's lemma to a set of sets of certain measures

Tags: measure-theory

Thank you for reading. I am trying to work through a problem. While I have been given an indication that everything else I have done is in the right place, I cannot figure out the step to complete the proof. It is as follows, rephrased here as a problem in itself:

Let $S:= \{X \in \Sigma \ | \ \mu(X) \leq c \}$ for some countably additive finite measure $\mu$ over a $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$. Apply Zorn's lemma to demonstrate $S$ has a maximal element $s$ such that $\forall s' \in S$, $\mu(s) \geq \mu(s')$.

As an aside, I know separately that for any $\epsilon > 0$ and $A \in \Sigma$, $\exists B \subset A$ in the $\sigma$-algebra such that $0 < \mu(B) < \epsilon$, although I do not think this helps here.

Thank you for taking a look at this. Additionally note that proving $S$ is uncountably large would allow me to finish the proof a different way, though I am equally stumped as to whether this is even possible.

Comment: Maybe try to show that whenever $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ is family of $\Sigma$, such that for any $i,j\in I$, $A_i\subset A_j$ or $A_j\subset A_i$, then $\mu(\displaystyle\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i)\leq sup_{i\in I}\mu(A_i)$ ? I don't know a lot about measure theory, but if you're supposed to use Zorn's lemma, this seems to be the right thing to do. Moreover, you can assume $S$ is at most countable, and then you can assume $I$ is at most countable as well (because you say you have another way of finishing when $S$ is uncountable)

Comment: I think the idea I gave works when $S$ is countable (since $\mu$ is countably additive), so you're left to deal with the uncountable case

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly the kind of thing I needed to see :)

Comment: I do not see how to deal with a particular uncountable case. Wouldn't the existence of a measurable cardinal contradict the above claim? The set $S:= \{X \in \Sigma \ | \ \mu(X) \leq 0 \}$ would not have a maximal element if you have a two-valued $\{0,1\}$ measure in which every set is measurable, and every singleton has measure $0$ (but the measure is non-trivial, and the whole space has measure $1$). So, perhaps what you are trying to prove is not a correct statement? For measurable cardinals see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_cardinal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know $\Sigma$ is a sigma-algebra, and so it's closed under complementation and countable union. Let $C$ denote the collection of all chains in $S$ partially ordered by inclusion. We know that all of these chains are countably infinite at best, since they are elements of a sigma-algebra. Let $C_\alpha\in C,$ then $C_\alpha$ has the form

$$C_\alpha= X_{\alpha_1}\subset X_{\alpha_2}\subset \cdots \subset X_{\alpha_n}\subset\cdots.$$

Define $\mu(C_\alpha),$ to be the sequence of real numbers ordered in the same fashion:

$$\mu(C_\alpha)= \mu X_{\alpha_1} \leq \mu X_{\alpha_2} \leq \cdots \leq \mu X_{\alpha_n} \leq \cdots \implies c_{\alpha_1}\leq c_{\alpha_2} \leq \cdots \leq c_{\alpha_n} \leq \cdots.$$

Thus, we have an increasing sequence of real numbers, bounded above by $c.$ So the monotone convergence theorem tells us that $\lim_{n\to\infty} c_{\alpha_n} = c_\alpha.$

Let $\{c_\alpha\}$ denote the set of all limits of sequences of this type. Then $\{c_\alpha\}\subset[0,c],$ and Bolzano Weierstrass tells us that this set $\{c_\alpha\}$ has a limit point, let us call it $c^\prime$. Let $\{c_{\alpha_n}^\prime\}$ be any sequence in $\{c_\alpha\}$ with this limit, then we take the chains associated to each $C_{\alpha_n},$ then you'll have to do some tedious arguing that you can build a new chain that is in $S,$ but it is doable. You may want to use a different definition of sigma-algebra which is equivalent "Any family of subsets of $X$ which is stable under differences and countable disjoint unions is a Sigma-algebra on $X.$"